# Function to add quarters represented as strings in Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

The main idea is to take string values that represent year+quarter concatenation in format `2020Q4`, `1999Q1`...ect and add/subtract an arbitrary number of quarters to/from them. These string values live in a 'polars' DataFrame in a column called 'quarter'. I want to create another column 'quarter_diff' where I subtract the previous row's  'quarter' from the current row's value.  The subtraction/addition should be smart enough to see that if it's `2020Q4`, by adding 1 quarter to it, it would be `2021Q1` and not `2020Q5`

Ideally it should be done with 'polars' own function since they are already optimised for speed.

Here is a function that is written in python, therefore not optimised for 'polars's speed or parallelisation and it only works for adding quarters, not subtracting them.

```
def add_quarter(quarter_str):
    year, quarter = quarter_str[:-2], quarter_str[-1]
    if quarter == '4':
        return f"{int(year) + 1}Q1"
    else:
        return f"{year}Q{int(quarter) + 1}"
```

Can anyone help in refactoring it for both addition as well as subtraction and for use of internal 'polars' function like maybe `offset_by()` or other?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use this**

This is a method that you monkey patch to the Expr namespace and then can use inside expressions. It allows any number of quarters to be added (I didn't test negative quarters but should work).

```
def add_quarters(self,Quarters=1):
    splt=self.str.split('Q')
    current=splt.arr.first().cast(pl.Float64()) + ((splt.arr.last().cast(pl.Float64()))-1)/4
    new_qt=current+Quarters/4
    new_yr=new_qt.floor().cast(pl.Int32()).cast(pl.Utf8())
    new_qtr=((new_qt*4).mod(4)+1).cast(pl.Int32()).cast(pl.Utf8())
    return new_yr + "Q" + new_qtr
pl.Expr.add_quarters=add_quarters
```

then you can do

```
df.with_columns(next_q=pl.col('quarter').add_quarters(2))

shape: (3, 2)
┌─────────┬────────┐
│ quarter ┆ next_q │
│ ---     ┆ ---    │
│ str     ┆ str    │
╞═════════╪════════╡
│ 2020Q4  ┆ 2021Q2 │
│ 2021Q1  ┆ 2021Q3 │
│ 2020Q2  ┆ 2020Q4 │
└─────────┴────────┘
```

**This was my first thought, keeping for thought process/appendix**

This uses split instead of the index of the character string but same principle as your python function...

If you have

```
df=pl.DataFrame({'quarter':["2020Q4", "2021Q1", "2020Q2"]})
```

then you can do

```
df \
    .with_columns(splt=pl.col("quarter").str.split('Q')) \
    .with_columns(Year=pl.col('splt').arr.first().cast(pl.Int32()), Quarter=pl.col('splt').arr.last().cast(pl.Int32())) \
    .drop('splt') \
    .with_columns(next_quarter=pl.when(pl.col("Quarter")==4)
                            .then((pl.col('Year')+1).cast(pl.Utf8()) + "Q1")
                            .otherwise((pl.col('Year').cast(pl.Utf8())) + "Q" + (pl.col('Quarter')+1).cast(pl.Utf8()))) \
    .drop(["Year",'Quarter'])
    

shape: (3, 2)
┌─────────┬──────────────┐
│ quarter ┆ next_quarter │
│ ---     ┆ ---          │
│ str     ┆ str          │
╞═════════╪══════════════╡
│ 2020Q4  ┆ 2021Q1       │
│ 2021Q1  ┆ 2021Q2       │
│ 2020Q2  ┆ 2020Q3       │
└─────────┴──────────────┘
```

**Second Thought**
You can consolidate that into your own Expression like this...

```
def add_quarter(self):
    splt=self.str.split('Q')
    Year=splt.arr.first().cast(pl.Int32())
    Quarter=splt.arr.last().cast(pl.Int32())
    return pl.when(Quarter==4).then((Year+1).cast(pl.Utf8()) + "Q1").otherwise(Year.cast(pl.Utf8()) + "Q" + (Quarter+1).cast(pl.Utf8()))
pl.Expr.add_quarter=add_quarter
```

then just...

```
df.with_columns(next_q=pl.col('quarter').add_quarter())
```

Comment: Thanks. This way it uses the polars’s internal properly. Nice.